# EntityDataSource Control in Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net

I am creating a `windows form application` and `ADO.Net Entity Framework`.
I am trying to get **EntityDataSource** Control in my toolbar but fail to do so.
Please can anyone guide me in doing so.

I am using **VS 2010** and **Framework 4.0**

P.S:

1. I have searched on internet and found that the control becomes visible when we choose to create a web application.
2. The real problem i am trying to solve is to show up referential data in the `datagrid view` as a drop down item (`Combobox`)

Is there any way i can have that control used in Windows Forms ?

Comment: See this example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms

Comment: @Sac : Thanks for the link , but i have already seen this link and this link uses the custom control/ library . But i wish to use the control provided by dotNet in Framework 4.0, is it not possible ?

Comment: Checkout the following link. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html